# How do i set threshold per each file using nyc Istanbul CLI reporter?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, istanbul

I was using Istanbul reporter for code coverage , when i tried to set thresholds in `.istanbul.YML`

```
check:
    global:
        statements: 60
        lines: 100
        branches: 50
        functions: 60
        excludes: []
    each:
        statements: 100
        lines: 100
        branches: 100
        functions: 100
        excludes: []
```

Coverage files when it doesn't meet the threshold but coverage percentage of running **istanbul** cover and **istanbul check-coverage** is different so planned to use **nyc** i configured it to

```
    .nycrc

    {
    "lines": 50,
    "statements": 50,
    "functions": 50,
    "branches": 50,
    "reporter": [
        "lcov",
        "text-summary"
    ],
    "extension": [
      ".jsx"
    ],
    "check-coverage": true
}
```

I'm able to set coverage threshold globally, but how can i set threshold per file basis or get the coverage percentage correctly in istanbul.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

"per-file": true